# Unsuccessful using SharedPreferences to save score in game. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: android

I've made a very basic clicker game. The problem is that every time I close the app, the score resets to zero. I read up on SharedPreferences, but the ones I've created to save and retrieve the data don't work. Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    TextView textView1;
    EditText editText1;
    Button button1;
    int counter = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        {textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);}}

@Override      
 protected void onStop()
        {super.onStop();
        SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("MySharedPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putInt("key", counter);
        editor.commit();}

@Override
    protected void onStart()
        {super.onStart();
        SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("MySharedPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int defaultValue = 0;
        int counter = prefs.getInt("key", defaultValue);}

    public void onClick(View v){
        if (v == button1){
            counter++;
            editText1.setText(Integer.toString(counter));}}}
```

On line 30 the "counter" says unable to access variable. Are there any solutions to this? Any help would be appreciated; I've tried reading more documentation,but I can't make any sense of it.

Comment: int counter = prefs.getInt("key", defaultValue);} gives you a new local variable

Comment: where are the `@override` annotations for `onStop()` `onStart()` ?

Comment: I'll add the annotations. Line 30, where the code is trying to call the saved number it says that the counter variable was unable to be accessed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have redeclared counter variable and it lost scope to be accessed in entire class.

```
int counter = prefs.getInt("key", defaultValue);
```

remove **int** declaration again in the **onStart()** method

into

```
 counter = prefs.getInt("key", defaultValue);
```